# Output of the following code- macros in c

Tags: c, macros

For the following code I am getting output as- Geeks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ISEQUAL(X, Y) X == Y
int main()
{
    #if ISEQUAL(X, 0)
        printf("Geeks");
    #else
        printf("Quiz");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Explain the reason for such output.

Comment: Note: you should **always** parenthetise macro arguments in the body. Otherwise, you might get wrong results due to _operator preceedence_. These are often pretty hard to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional macro `#if ISEQUAL(X, 0)` is expanded to `#if X == 0`. After the pre-processing is over, all the undefined macros are initialized with default value `0`. Since macro `X` has not been defined, it is initialized with `0`. So, "Geeks" is printed.

Comment: "After the pre-processing is over, ..." Well, after preprocessing, nothing is done actually with macros anymore. If `X` is not defined when the `#if` is evaluated, it is simply deemed `0`, but not "initialized" (which would define it actually)